# Edit Etherpad in Markdown Editor?

Tags: markdown

Alright, this is somewhat difficult ... I have to work on a Markdown file simultaneously with a friend, so we want to use Etherpad to see each other's edits in realtime. However, if we write Markdown in our browsers, we won't see a live preview of the Markdown code. So is there a way to open an Ehterpad link in our respective Markdown editors with the Etherpad sill being synced?

Too further complicate things, we're using different operating systems and Markdown editors (Windows 7 / 8 with MarkdownPad and Mac OS with Macdown).

Is there a way to do this? We have a server that we could potentially use to run our own Etherpad installation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the etherpad markdown plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_markdown
But you might also need other plugins, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_headings_css to actually have some formatting available in the first place.